# Airflow task Intermittently Fails due to Failed to fetch log file and Could not read logs

Tags: airflow

I'm running a DAG that runs once per day. It starts with 9 concurrently running tasks that all do the same thing - each is basically polling S3 to see if that tasks's designated 1 file exists. Each task is the same code in Airflow and is put into the structure in the same way. I have 1 of these tasks, which, on random days, fails to "begin" - it won't enter the `running` stage. It just sits as `queued` . When it does this, here's what its log says

```
*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://:8793/log/my.dag.name./my_airflow_task/2020-03-14T07:00:00
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker.

*** Reading remote logs...
Could not read logs from s3://mybucket/airflow/logs/my.dag.name./my_airflow_task/2020-03-14T07:00:00
```

Why does this only happen on random days? All similar questions I've seen point to this error happening consistently, and once overcome, no longer continues. To "trick" this task into "running" I manually `touch` whatever the name of the log file is supposed to be, and then it changes to `running`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue appears that it had to do with the system's ownership rules regarding the folder the logs for that particular task wrote to. I used a CI tool to ship the new `task_3` when I updated my Airflow's Python code to the production environment, so the task was created that way. When I peaked for log directory ownership,  I noticed this for the tasks:

```
# inside/airflow/log/dir: 

drwxrwxr-x 2 root    root     4096 Mar 25 14:53 task_3  # is the offending task
drwxrwxr-x 2 airflow airflow 20480 Mar 25 00:00 task_2
drwxrwxr-x 2 airflow airflow 20480 Mar 25 15:54 task_1
```

So, I think what was going on, was that randomly, Airflow couldn't get the permission to write the log file, thus it wouldn't start the rest of the task. When I applied the appropriate `chown` command using something like `sudo chown -R airflow:airflow task_3` . Ever since I changed this, the issue has disappeared.